# Why was this slightly unusual flight path followed?

Tags: flight-path

I was just browsing the flight paths when I saw this:
[image]
([FlightRadar24: SN2825 from BRU to BUD on 26 Jul 2022](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/sn2825#2ccde5e0))

But normally the path is straighter like this (not flying over Zurich):
[image]
([FlightRadar24: SN2825 from BRU to BUD on 25 Jul 2022](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/sn2825#2cca49e9))

I have seen even more deviation, like flying above Venice. This all adds some time to the total flight time.

Why is that? How can I know the reason?

Comment: Have you looked at weather maps and airspace closures at the time of the route?

Comment: Hi Akos, welcome to aviation.stackexchange. Please add the date of the flights to the question by using the edit function. WIthout knowing the date/time of these flight paths, it is going to be very hard to get a reliable answer.

Comment: I updated the date/time (without links), but the radar url's are also available now. Hopefully they remain accessible over time.

Comment: @RonBeyer well, that could be a sufficient explanation for me. Even if I don't find such a map (where can I view the weather at a given point in the past, or the airspace closures, without any subscription). I would never have imagined of closures or such 'bad' weather to make such detour anyways, especially because other flights didn't make that deviation. But sometimes it is even a larger curve, down to Venice as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This should explain it. Aircraft had to divert because of weather. this was the forecast for Thursday, but it was like this Tuesday as well. [image: There were severe storms all across Germany during the week.]

Comment: I doubt that was the reason. We didn't have any rain yesterday in west Germany, e.g. Frankfurt reported 0mm rain yesterday ([source](https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather-history/Frankfurt/metric/2022-07-26/2022-07-26)). Also, other flights in a similar direction flew the normal route without the detour (e.g. [SN2905](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/BEL2905/history/20220726/1350Z/EBBR/LOWW) to Vienna).

Comment: Check out [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDoYN.jpg) from [FR24's playback feature](https://www.flightradar24.com/2022-07-26/16:00/12x/BEL6PR/2ccde5e0). There are many other aircraft in that area.

Comment: @Bianfable I would argue that that is neither how weather works, nor how airline dispatching works. Just because _you_ didnt see the weather doesnt mean it wasn't there, and just because _some_ airlines chose to go through/over the weather doesn't mean all will.

Comment: @Jamiec OK, maybe there was weather to avoid, but this answer doesn't show at all that this weather existed. The map is for a Thursday (tomorrow? last week?). I can't find a historical weather radar map of the region, but the forecast for 1500UTC (17:00 local) looked like [this](https://youtu.be/WYNjA4sqY1Y?t=900) the evening before. Until evidence of thunderstorms is added to this answer, this is IMHO just speculation.

Comment: @Bianfable That I don't disagree with!

Comment: @Bianfable You don't have to have rain to be asked or told to divert for weather.  "I can't find a historical weather radar map of the region..." So let me know when you do. You also don't need to have thunderstorms to divert, because turbulence doesn't require a thunderstorm either. This is Private Pilot 101 stuff, not rocket science.